# DLL not able to access Database used internally on IIS for ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, iis, windows-server

While developing a simple ASP.NET application that queries certain parameters from a DLL file and outputs results as processed by the DLL itself, I faced the challenge to host it on an IIS server. Note: the DLL uses a `.mdb` database for internal processing. When I run my code on debug mode through the Visual studio locally, via localhost its running perfectly fine. But When I host the same piece of code to IIS its reading the DLL but the DLL is not able to access the database. Mostly I think it must be a permissions or authorization issue, but don't really know what can be done in the Windows ecosystem to solve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Add permission on the database file for iis_users and give it full control
from windows explorer right click db file - security tab.